# Generating large JSON file with millions of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm working on a project using mostly JavaScript, and I want to know if there is a way that I can generate a massive JSON file in which is just an array of objects but can hold say... over a billion objects!

The objects literally only contain numbers from 1 > some inputNum (inputNum *could* be a number like 999,999,999,999 for example). This is so that my team and I don't have to keep counting up to really large numbers, pushing up to an array, and having constant memory leaks while we work and calculate our data. Our data being really large and annoying numbers.

I have the code for creating the JSON object and pushing it and it works, but it seems to not be able to keep counting past a certain large number (999,999 was the highest I could get it to), then I run out of memory and cannot complete the task. I tried to break the JSON files up into maybe "chunks" so I could maybe "stitch" them together, haha, but when I tried to count up from a high number like say: 999,999 up to 999,999,999 to continue my sequence count in order, my console crashed...

I know it's a lot of writes and pushes, but this won't be for consumers either and it will be stored on our client-side as well on a dedicated storage device, so the file size isn't a worry. Is this a possible task for JavaScript? What could be a solution to performing this task?

An example of my object is for reference:

`[ { "i": 1, "iSquared": 2 }, { "i": 2, "iSquared": 4 }, { "i": 3, "iSquared": 6 }, ... { "i": 999999999, "iSquared": 9.99999998e17 } ]`

Again, I know it's insane! It may not even have to be that high of a number either, but what is the highest I could count and push to a JSON file to?

**Here's the code:**

```
const fs = require("fs");

let inputNum = 9999999;

async function readSequenceJSON() {
  let data = await fs.promises.readFile("./numberline.json");
  return JSON.parse(data);
}

function writeSequenceJSON(data) {
  let str = JSON.stringify(data);
  return fs.promises.writeFile("./numberline.json", str);
}

async function nextSequence(inputNum) {
  let data = await readSequenceJSON();

  for (let i = 0; i <= inputNum; i++) {
    let iSquared = i + i;

    data.push({ i, iSquared });
  }

  writeSequenceJSON(data);
}

nextSequence(inputNum)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("done");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have your answer.

This must be the memory issue.

There isn't any such thing like **the highest I could count and push to a JSON file**. A file can be as large as the OS limitation.

Don't keep your JSON data in memory, rather, keep them in the database. MongoDB is designed to serve data in JSON format.

Comment: I appreciate the answer and checking into MongoDB now. Any advice looking at my code above, how I could prepare it for MongoDB? Thank you!

Comment: @KingMuze `npm install mongodb` may be your first step. You may push each of your JSON objects to the DB using sequential primary keys. Then you can take `inputNum` and make reference, I guess.

Comment: Better still, switch languages.  This seems like more of a job for Python and/or Numpy and/or R.  I'm sure there's a way to do this with JavaScript, but it really just isn't designed to manipulate this kind of data.